# How to unregister utility previously registered?

Tags: plone, zope

I would like to remove a previously registered utility, specifically, the portal-catalog utility registered by collective.indexing from my product.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [z3c.unconfigure](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.unconfigure)

Comment: I suspect the OP is trying to remove a persistent component, not something hooked up in ZCML.

Comment: nope... i need to undo the utility registration from another product... simahawk's approach seems to make sense

Answer (score 0):

If you do in fact have a local utility that you need to remove, take a look at:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/manually-removing-local-persistent-utilities/